# $location.path for browser back button

Tags: angularjs, location

Hi I am in very similar scenario like this js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jccrosby/eRGT8/light/
but I want the browser back button work as you go through each tab.
Here is another link from JS fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/uDPHL/
that works with browser back button but it triggered from ng-class function and I want to do from ng-click and its also not working in IE8. Below the code I tried but it didn't worked.

```
$scope.currentTab = $location.path(tab.url);
```

Any suggestion

UPDATE - As per one answer below. The sate needs to be change/updated. So why the state is changing when clicking browser back button on ng-class function and not in ng-click function

```
 $scope.navClass = function (page) {
    var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1);
    return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
};   

 $scope.navClick = function (page) {
     $scope.testURL = $location.path()
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For browser back button to work, you should change the state when a tab is selected like in the working example.

In the working example, browser history is changing because of `href="#"`, but is not triggered from `ngClass`. Here, `ng-class` is only used to change the css class based on the current state.

Call this method on `ng-click` which changes the browser url and sets the $scope.currentTab value

```
$scope.changeUrl = function(url) {
  $location.path('#'+url); 
  $scope.currentTab = url;
}
```

Comment: So, then this should work from ng-click $scope.currentTab = $location.path('#'+tab.url); I'll do a quick test.

Comment: $location.path('#'+tab.url) setter doesn't return any value.. you should assign it manually.. check the updated answer